# request.resolver_match.kwargs only works while inside for loop?

Tags: python, django

I'm using request.resolver_match.kwargs with django to grab the url param for a view I'm trying to link to. When I use it as so

`<a href="{% url 'ViewPdf' uid=request.resolver_match.kwargs.uid %}">Print this page</a>`

I get a noreversematch error. however if I put it inside a for loop it works as so

```
   {% for uid in request.resolver_match.kwargs.uid %}            
   <a href="{% url 'ViewPdf' uid=request.resolver_match.kwargs.uid %}">Print this page</a>
   {% endfor %}
```

With the obvious side effect of having as many links as there are characters in the url param. I'm not sure why it works in the for loop but not as a standalone.

Comment: I'd check that you're getting the expected datatype. Possibly you're sending a string, but the url resolver is expecting an integer.

Comment: Please show the URL pattern and the full text of the error. My guess is you have `[0-9]` instead of `[0-9]+`, so only single digits are valid in the URL.

Comment: Reverse for 'ViewPdf' with keyword arguments '{'uid': ''}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['ViewPdf/(?P<uid>.+)/', 'app/ViewPdf/(?P<uid>.+)/']

Comment: url(r'^ViewPdf/(?P<uid>.+)/', views.ViewPDF, name='ViewPdf')

Comment: `'{'uid': ''}'` surprises me - if `uid` is evaluating to the empty string I would expect `{% for uid ... %}` to loop zero times. Please show the entire view and template. I would also try temporarily removing the loop and url tag temporarily, and checking `{{ request.resolver_match.kwargs.uid }}`. What URL are you on when the error occurs?